# Ejecutar un código al dar al botón de volver atrás o salir la app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Me gustaría saber como ejecutar un código cuando el usuario vuelva atrás con el botón de su smartphone y salga de ese activity, y ejecutar un código tambien al salir de la aplicación ( en segundo plano )

Lo que quiero con ello es que al salir de un activity donde se reproduce un sonido, si le dan atrás y salen de ese activity o saliendo y teniendo la app en segundo plano, ese sonido se pare con release()

Answer (score 0):

Para detectar el botón de regreso y finalizar la activity, sobre escribe el método `onBackPressed()`   y usa `finish()` para terminar la `Activity`:

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        finish();
    }
```

Si deseas llamar un método al salir y destruirse la Activity sobre escribe el método `onDestroy()`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() { 
    //Realiza un proceso.
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Si deseas detectar cuando tu aplicación pasa a segundo plano sobre escribe el método `onPause()`, aquí puedes llamar `.release()` :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    myMediaPlayer.release();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando una Activity se pone en pausa o finaliza se ejecutan una serie de métodos que puedes sobreescribir, te los dejo a continuación:
[image: Ciclo de vida de una aplicación Android]

El siguiente método te ayudará:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //Aquí el código que quieras ejecutar al finalizar el Activity

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Entonces en mi caso, si se sale del activity sería onDestroy y si salgo de la app dejandola en segundo plano sería onStop ¿ Es correcto ?

Comment: Exacto, lo mejor es que sobreescribas todos los métodos imprimiendo un mensaje en cada uno de ellos y veas como funciona.